# Inconsistent SSH public key gives a Permission denied

Tags: ssh

I recently found out that the public key file (`.pub`) generated by `ssh-keygen` was **actually used** to authenticate.

I had an old key pair `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and I replaced **only the private key** with a new one, without deleting or updating the public key file accordingly. And this setup give me a `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)` error.

If I delete the old public key file, it works fine. If I generate a public key file from the new private key, it works fine too.

I was wondering if this behavior was documented somewhere? I didn't manage to find any information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not clearly documented.

Public-key authentication in SSHv2 works like this:

1. Client offers a public key.
2. Server checks whether this key *may* be acceptable, and requests proof (signature).
3. Client sends a digital signature made using the corresponding private key.

If you have multiple keypairs for different sets of servers, the client will try to offer all of them, until it finds one that the server is willing to accept.

But with the 'PEM' key file format, if the private key is encrypted, it gets encrypted in full – you cannot even extract the public parameters from it – which means the client would need to prompt you for passphrases of each key that you have, until it finally finds a match.

So in order to avoid that, the OpenSSH client always uses `.pub` files for the initial offer – it doesn't try to decrypt the private-key files until it knows whether the server is willing to accept those keys in the first place. And of course **that means the client is unable to check whether the two files match before this happens.**

(PuTTY's 'PPK' key format does not have this problem. The newer 'OpenSSH' private key format also appears to store the public key in plain, and looks like OpenSSH 8.3 finally added support for *using* it, but even then only if the corresponding `.pub` file is missing.)